# Java-Hashed password value is null

Tags: spring, hash, null, passwords, bcrypt

Hello I have spent several hours trying to figure out **why my hashed password is null.** I am trying to use Spring BCryptPasswordEncoder. I have read several documentations, looked at many different examples, and watched videos on how to use this encryptor but I just can't get it to work. Looking at my MYSQL database I know the password field is populated, but the field for hashPassword remains null. Before anyone flips out I know that the plain password should not be stored in the database, but at the moment this is how I know that the password parameter is not null. As far as I know this is not a duplicate question and if so please direct me to right place, because everything I have seen for the hashing category has not been helpful. Below is a snippet of the code I am using if you need more detail please let me know.

```
    @Entity
          public class User {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue
            private int uid;

            @NotNull
            @Column(unique = true )
            private String username;

            @NotNull
            private String password;

            @Column
            private String hashedPassword;

             private static final BCryptPasswordEncoder encodedPassword = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

           public User(String username, String password) {
                this.username = username;
                this.password = password;
                this.hashedPassword = hashIt(this.password);

            }
public User() { }
      public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
      public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
     public String getHashedPassword() {
            return hashedPassword;
        }
     public void setHashedPassword(String hashedPassword) {
            this.hashedPassword = hashedPassword;
        }

         public String hashIt(String password) {
                return encodedPassword.encode(password);
            }

         public boolean isCorrectPassword(String password){

                return encodedPassword.matches(password,hashedPassword);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you talking about `hashIt` returning null, or something else?

Comment: I'm sorry.  Its hashPassword returning null and hashIt i

Comment: I'm sorry.  Its hashedPassword returning null and hashIt is the method that performs the encoding.

Comment: `hashedPassword` is a property. It doesn't return anything. What value are you actually trying to assign to it? Worth using a debugger here to find out.

Comment: It does return something. The problem was with @Model Attribute in my controller. I have removed the attribute from my controller and now it works as it should. Thanks anyway.